# Have a notification notify outside of the app (android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, notifications

- I have an ArrayList containing an int for the hour of the day and an int for the minute of the day. I would like to send out a notification whenever the current time of day equals the time in the arraylist
- Whenever I run the code the notification only appears if I start the app at a time in the arraylist
- I would like the notification to appear even if the user is outside of the application
- I believe my problem is that my notification is currently stored in my onCreate() section, however I have no idea where to place it to make the notification appear when the user isn't in the application

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        int notifyID = 1;
        String CHANNEL_ID = "Class Over";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            CharSequence name = "my_channel_name";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            mChannel.setDescription("notification channel description");
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
        Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < classes.size(); i++) {
            if (rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == classes.get(i).getClassHour() && rightNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == classes.get(i).getClassMin()) {

                NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                        .setContentTitle("Any Homework for " + classes.get(i).getClassName())
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
                NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
                notificationManager.notify(notifyID, notification.build());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To schedule jobs in android, you need to understand job schedulers or 
fireBaseJobDispatcher, you might also need broadCast receivers depending on the conditions you want your notification to load,
some useful links :) https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        remoteMessage.getNotification();

    }

    if (remoteMessage.getData() != null) {

        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

        String message = data.get("message");

  generateNotification(this,message, false);   
  }
}
}

public void generateNotification(Context context, String message, boolean isSilent) {


    // Message does not null or empty
    if (CommonUtil.isNullString("" + message)) {
        return;
    }


    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;


        Bitmap notificationLargeIconBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_img);


        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_img);
               .setLargeIcon(notificationLargeIconBitmap);



        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, ProfileNavigationActivity.class);

        resultIntent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_NOTIFICATION, Constants.INTENT_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);

        resultIntent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE, "" + message);

        resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(),
                resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        mBuilder.setContentText("" + message);
        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();

        mBuilder.setPublicVersion(notification);
        // If isSilent flag is true, does not make sound and vibrate.
        if (!isSilent) {
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        }

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Notification id allows you to updateFragment the notification later on.
        if (mNotificationManager != null) {
            mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
        }
    }
```